# Full width "add to cart" button on desktop

Tags: magento2

i am trying to modify the css of -add to cart- button to be always full width on desktop. I noticed it is already full width on mobile. I am having a hard time finding the code.

I have found that this controlls the padding .product-info-main .box-tocart .action.tocart but there is nothing else....

How can this be done?
This is magento 2.4.4.

(ATTACHED PICTURE)
[image]

Comment: Please share the page url.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, i am working on a local host, i will try to get it online...but its the default blank theme......it came like this...